# "Genotype structure"?

Tags: genetics, allele

What does a geneticist mean when they write "genotype structure", e.g. the sentence "...represents continuous allele frequencies for both tumor and normal samples, while leveraging the expected genotype structure of the normal."

Citation: http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/28/14/1811.long

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add a citation to where you read this. Context is very important.

Comment: Sorry about that @MattDMo

Comment: The line can be found in the Results subsection of the Abstract in the second sentence @MattDMo